# Regexp for not letting a number begin with 0

Tags: regex

i need help with a regexp.

It will be allowed to use 0-9 and allowed length is 2 or 3, but not if it begins with 0.

My exp:

```
^[0-9]{2,3}$
```

this allows ex. 03 or 033, but it should be disallowed.

Comment: What program will be consuming your regexp?

Comment: also, what language is the regex used in? This should be simple enough the dialect shouldn't matter too much, but it's important that you also tag where it's going to be used.

Comment: is `03` a valid result or not? Your last sentence isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just split it in 2 parts: 1st digit and other digits.

```
^[1-9][0-9]{1,2}$
```

Comment: It misses the handling of "0" and of single-digit numbers.

Comment: 0 starts with 0, so in context of this question, 0 isn't a valid number.

Answer (score 2):

Take your pick:

```
^[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2}$

^[0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]?$

^0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$

^0|[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?$
```

I'd personally choose the second-to-last or last one.

You can notice only the "0" case needs a particular match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very simple regex like this:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/dK9wL9/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]